# Facebook Messenger Platform -> Subscribed Apps with graph-api not working for me

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger

I am trying to develop one-click-integration support for my bot, which will include FB messenger.
For the FB messenger I did the following:

1. Followed the "[quick-start](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/guides/quick-start/)" guide and created a Facebook App.
2. Followed the "[facebook-login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login)" tutorial and deployed a facebook login process which works with permissions for:
       - public_profile
       - email
       - manage_pages
       - pages_show_list
       - pages_messaging_subscriptions
       - pages_messaging
3. I then used the graph-api of '/me/accounts' to get list of pages name , page ids, and access_token under a "test user" I created in facebook.
4. Now, I picked a page under this "test user" (with all the permissions), and tried to run this JS code -

```js
FB.api(
      `/${page.id}/subscribed_apps?access_token=${page.access_token}`,
      function (response) {        
        console.log(`response = {$JSON.stringify(response)}`);
        if (response && !response.error) {          
          /* handle the result */
        }
      }
    );
```

The problem:  I get response = {"data":[]} , which might be OK, but when I look at the page->settings->Messenger Platform->Subscribed Apps , I don't see any app subscribed there.
By the way, When I run this without the proper access_token , I do get an error #210 ("needs access_token") which is as expected...

Any idea how to subscribe the app properly to the page?
Must say I also tried it with the graph api explorer tool and got the same result...

Thanks in advance :-).

Comment: It needs to be a POST request.

Comment: Hey @CBroe - thanks for helping out. is worked :-).

Answer (score 0):

@CBroe got it correct and there were 2 issues:
 1. I should have used the POST() instead of GET() method.
 2. When you use the graph-api-explorer tool, you will see it works, then role down and get the JS code... problem is the code is a bit confusing since what you get is this:

```js
FB.api(
  `/${my_page_id}/subscribed_apps`,
  'POST',
  {},
  function(response) {
      // Insert your code here
  }
);
```

but, it should actually be like this:

```js
FB.api(
  `/${my_page_id}/subscribed_apps`,
  'POST',
  {"access_token": `${page_access_token}`},
  function(response) {
      // Insert your code here
  }
);
```

remeber to take the access_token from the /me/accounts api as I described in my question.

Thanks again to @CBroe for showing me how to solve this :-)